# CSS Flexbox layout not working as per expectation

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

I have hosted my react app on the below link -

https://surijatin.github.io/covid-second-dose/

I am using CSS Flexbox for the layout. When I go below 560px(for a mobile phone screen), the Vaccine selection buttons aren't aligned in columns properly. There is some weird overlapping there.
Can someone please help me and point me in the right direction? I have been brainstorming on this since a few hours now.

Github repo - https://github.com/surijatin/covid-second-dose

Comment: Try making the <label> elements have `display: block;` – by default they are `inline`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've written your `flex` CSS in the wrong element or missing to write on the appropriate element. You have to add the CSS to -

```
.main-wrapper > div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

More specifically, if you want to apply the CSS to the first encountered `div` element then try this-

```
.main-wrapper > div:first-of-type {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

> The [`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) CSS pseudo-class represents the first element of its type among a group of sibling elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can give the `div` element who contain the overlapping elements a class of `cont-box`
and update your css with follwing

```
@media(max-width:560px){
 .cont-box{
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
 }
}
```